# Using smtp.gmail.com as postfix relay - some mails are marked as spam

Tags: postfix, smtp

I have my server configured to send mails via a professional google account using smtp.gmail.com as postfix relay and some of the mails are being marked as spam upon delivery. It does also depend on the day. Sometimes, I test sending to my professional account and it does get blocked. however, today, it does not get marked as spam.
How can I mitigate or improve the chances of not getting my mails marked as spam? - I was thinking about asking my users to whitelist my domain, but that seems a bit unprofessional, although, I see it many times on legitimate mails I receive.

**** UPDATE 1:

This is a log example of a mail that DOES get sent and NOT MARKED as spam:

```
Dec  9 13:48:00 ns3106841 postfix/anvil[20199]: statistics: max connection rate 1/60s for (smtp:<my.server.ip.address>) at Dec  9 13:43:25
Dec  9 13:48:00 ns3106841 postfix/anvil[20199]: statistics: max connection count 1 for (smtp:<my.server.ip.address>) at Dec  9 13:43:25
Dec  9 13:48:00 ns3106841 postfix/anvil[20199]: statistics: max cache size 1 at Dec  9 13:43:25
Dec  9 13:48:53 ns3106841 postfix/pickup[20170]: C9B15202C7: uid=0 from=<root>
Dec  9 13:48:53 ns3106841 postfix/cleanup[20359]: C9B15202C7: message-id=<20191209134853.C9B15202C7@my.domain.com>
Dec  9 13:48:53 ns3106841 postfix/qmgr[20171]: C9B15202C7: from=<root@ns3106841.ip-54-37-81.eu>, size=318, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec  9 13:48:54 ns3106841 postfix/smtp[20361]: C9B15202C7: to=<my.mail@address.com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[108.177.15.109]:587, delay=1.1, delays=0.01/0.01/0.22/0.91, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1575899334 i16sm13715549wmb.36 - gsmtp)
Dec  9 13:48:55 ns3106841 postfix/cleanup[20359]: F3F60202C8: message-id=<20191209134854.F3F60202C8@my.domain.com>
Dec  9 13:48:55 ns3106841 postfix/bounce[20364]: C9B15202C7: sender delivery status notification: F3F60202C8
Dec  9 13:48:55 ns3106841 postfix/qmgr[20171]: F3F60202C8: from=<>, size=2269, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Dec  9 13:48:55 ns3106841 postfix/qmgr[20171]: C9B15202C7: removed
Dec  9 13:48:56 ns3106841 postfix/smtp[20361]: F3F60202C8: to=<root@ns3106841.ip-54-37-81.eu>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[108.177.15.109]:587, delay=1.1, delays=0.01/0/0.19/0.86, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 OK  1575899336 w17sm27693730wrt.89 - gsmtp)
Dec  9 13:48:56 ns3106841 postfix/qmgr[20171]: F3F60202C8: removed
Dec  9 13:48:56 ns3106841 postfix/smtpd[20365]: connect from mail-wm1-f44.google.com[209.85.128.44]
Dec  9 13:48:56 ns3106841 postfix/smtpd[20365]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from mail-wm1-f44.google.com[209.85.128.44]: 454 4.7.1 <root@ns3106841.ip-54-37-81.eu>: Relay access denied; from=<> to=<root@ns3106841.ip-54-37-81.eu> proto=ESMTP
helo=<mail-wm1-f44.google.com>
Dec  9 13:48:56 ns3106841 postfix/smtpd[20365]: disconnect from mail-wm1-f44.google.com[209.85.128.44] ehlo=2 starttls=1 mail=1 rcpt=0/1 data=0/1 quit=1 commands=5/7
```

**** UPDATE 2:

I changed "myorigin" in main.cf to my FQDN - so far, the reject messages stopped appearing, however:

I get mails sent to my mail account and I noticed on my exchange server (Office365) the mails are being rejected in a pretty random way:

```
Reason: [{LED=550 4.3.2 QUEUE.TransportAgent; message deleted by transport agent};{MSG=};{FQDN=};{IP=};{LRT=}]
```

This is non consistent because some emails seem to get filtered as spam and the next mail, an hour later might not.

**** UPDATE 3:

main.cf

```
myorigin = <server.FQDN>

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = <server.FQDN>
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
#myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = <server.FQDN>, localhost.<server.FQDN>, localhost
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +

smtp_connection_cache_on_demand = yes
smtp_connect_timeout = 20
smtp_helo_timeout = 40
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
smtp_use_tls = yes
inet_protocols = ipv4
#inet_interfaces = loopback-only
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl/passwd
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

Comment: Including mail server logs or email headers showing your mail being marked as spam would be helpful in determining ways to improve your situation.

Comment: I will look for the logs, once I get another blacklisted mail: In the meantime, I noticed the reply address is a generic noreply @noreply.my.domain ... I think that's something that could give me some issues.

Comment: Updated the OP with some logs I gathered

Comment: Can you also include your `postfix.conf`

Comment: google deny to use its own as relay. your server ns3106841.ip-54-37-81.eu may not be allowed to use it. sofar either try to auth yozr self or dont use gmail as relayhost in main.cf

Comment: Update #3 added: main.cf pasted.